# Stubbing two methods exported from the same file using Sinon

Tags: javascript, node-modules, sinon

I'm a newbie to JavaScript and need help in unit-testing my code.
There is an existing file `F1.js` whose methods I'm using in my implementation. The file looks like this:

**F1.js :**

```
function A({p1, p2}, callback) {

}

function B(q1, q2) {

}

module.exports = A;
module.exports.B = callbackify(B);
```

My file `Sol.js` uses these functions as,

**Sol.js:**

```
const A = require('/F1');
const {
  B 
} = require('/F1');


somefunction() {



   B( param1, param2, (err, result) => {
      A( {anotherParam, result}, 
         function (err, result2) {
             // do something with result2

         }
      ) 
   })

}
```

I'm trying to unit test the method `somefunction` and struggling with the stubbing. Here is how I mock the functions

**Sol_Test.js**

```
B_stub = sinon
      .stub()
      .callsFake((param1, param2, callback) => callback(null, result1));

A_stub = sinon
      .stub()
      .callsFake(({ param1, param2 }, cb) => cb(null, result2));

return proxyquire(
   'F1' : {
        A_stub,
        B : B_stub,
   }
)
```

I'm getting the error :  `B is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution and sharing it here in case someone else needs it :D

Modified `Sol.js` as below

```
const A = require('/F1');


somefunction() {



   A.B( param1, param2, (err, result) => {
      A( {anotherParam, result}, 
         function (err, result2) {
             // do something with result2

         }
      ) 
   })

}
```

Changed the stubbing in unit test :

```
B_stub = sinon
      .stub()
      .callsFake((param1, param2, callback) => callback(null, result1));

A_stub = sinon
      .stub()
      .callsFake(({ param1, param2 }, cb) => cb(null, result2));

A_stub.B = B_stub;

return proxyquire(
     '/F1': A_stub,
)
```